# Laravel 4 migration:install ErrorException

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

```
php artisan migrate:install

{"error":{"type":"ErrorException","message":"PDO::__construct(): [2002] Connection refused (trying to connect via tcp:\/\/127.0.0.1:3306)","file":"\/Applications\/MAMP\/htdocs\/DRCSports\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Database\/Connectors\/Connector.php","line":47}}
```

In my database.php I have updated the information to mysql

```
'mysql' => array(
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => '127.0.0.1',
        'database'  => 'Laravel_DRCSports',
        'username'  => 'root',
        'password'  => 'root',
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
    ),
```

I am not sure if I am understanding the error right, but to me it looks like my laravel isn't connecting to mysql right. If that is the case I have no clue how to fix it.

Comment: Looks like PDO can't open connection for this host:ip.

Are you sure there's mysql server on 127.0.0.1 with 3306 port? Did you tried to telnet
to this host and see if you're able to connect?

Comment: The port isn't 3306, it's 8888. I see that it's going to port 3306, I'm just not sure where I change it to 8888 at.

    telnet 127.0.0.1 8888
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
H
5.5.9g;0|Br8?Sd~m'xH@G#tFmysql_native_password

Comment: just add to the array: 'port' => 8888

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem was that mysql is running on port 8888, while Laravel's default port value is 3306 (as it's the default port of mysql servers).

The solution is to add 'port' key to the array (For example: 'port' => 8888) and it'll
do the work.

Answer (score 2):

This is what i did... in /app/config/app.php

```
'mysql' => array(
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => 'localhost:8889',
            'database'  => 'pic',
            'username'  => 'root',
            'password'  => 'root',
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',

        ),
```

and at the bottom of the php code

'redis' => array(

```
    'cluster' => false,

    'default' => array(
        'host'     => '127.0.0.1',
        'port'     => 8888,
        'database' => 0,
    ),

),
```

it has to work it...

Answer (score 0):

I experienced problems (Laravel 4) when I used MySQL on a port other than 3306.

A browser-run app expects the following app/config/database syntax:

```
'mysql' => array(
        ...
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'port' => '8889',
        ...
)
```

While the command-line run artisan expects the following syntax:

```
'mysql' => array(
        ...
    'host' => 'localhost:8889',
        ...
)
```

The issue is described here:
https://github.com/laravel/laravel/issues/1182

Most articles suggest a workaround using Laravel environments, but it results in duplicate config files and violates the DRY principle (Don't Repeat Yourself), so here's another alternative:

At the top of app/config/database.php:

```
$my_hostname = 'localhost';
$my_port     = '8889';
$my_database = 'database';
$my_username = 'username';
$my_password = 'password';

if (App::runningInConsole()) {        // artisan runs from the command line
    // change 'localhost' to 'localhost:8889'
    $my_hostname = $my_hostname.':'.$my_port;
}
```

And further down:

```
'mysql' => array(
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => $my_hostname,
    'port'      => $my_port,
    'database'  => $my_database,
    'username'  => $my_username,
    'password'  => $my_password,
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
),
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Change your database information in your config/database.php and .env file.

Answer (score 0):

I did these changes and worked like a champ :

in database.php :
host : localhost:8889
Port: 8889
and my mamp has a password so I there was two way to putting that password either in database.php file or in .env file I changed the password '' value to 'forge' and then use my MAMP password in the .env file 
by the way, you can see your specific information about MAMP in MAMP application in the port tab (MySQL one)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to edit this part of ".env" file.

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=8889
DB_DATABASE=blog
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

i guess you can solve this problem by add the following code inside app/config/database syntax:

```
'mysql' => array(
    ...

    'pconnect' => 'TRUE',
    ...
)
```