# php artisan migrate error PDOException in Laravel 4

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a problem to execute this:

```
$ php artisan migrate
```

I'm getting an error

```
[PDOException]                             
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused
```

I'm using MAMP and it's working ok.

I have tried to set the localhost to 127.0.0.1 and I've added `'unix_socket' => '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock'` but nothing helps.

[Edit]
also I've added the port and I have checked the user and the password are correct and the server is running properly.. any suggestion??

Thanks

Comment: What happens if you use a regular php script to connect to the database?

Comment: Also check your credentials (username and password)

Comment: Try connecting via your mysql console - doesn't sound like a Laravel problem at all.

Comment: The user name and the password are ok..so I don't know what's happening. I have added the port but it doesn´t help.

Comment: As halfer mentions,doesnt look like a Laravel problem. Try to connect to mysql using console or workbench(Can you connect here?). Also, do verify the port number, mamp has different default port. Set it to 3306 for mysql.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure but make sure your `mysql server` is running and it's running on the right port as expected because, `Laravel`'s default port value is `3306` (it's the default port of `mysql` server) and most probably `mysql` is running on a different port. Here is a [discussion](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/issues/1182) and also check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16904470/laravel-4-migrationinstall-errorexception), it's almost similar.

Also follow [this thread](http://www.wolfcms.org/forum/topic1101.html) which discussed and solved the same error you mentioned in your question:

```
[SOLVED] SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused
```

Comment: it´s not working...     'mysql' => array(
   'driver'    => 'mysql',
   'host'      => 'localhost',
   'port'      => 8889,
   'database'  => 'FootballApp',
   'username'  => 'root',
   'password'  => 'root',
   'charset'   => 'utf8',
   'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
   'prefix'    => '',
  )

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old question, but it came up as the first result in Google when I had the same problem, so I wanted to add my solution here in case it helps someone else.

In MAMP when you click on MySQL, there is a setting to "Allow network access to MySQL" that needs to be enabled for Laravel to access the database (it wasn't enabled by default for me). This allows your application to connect to MySQL without using a Unix socket.

Comment: New answers to old questions are always encouraged.

Comment: This was exactly the issue. As soon as clicked on the option and restarted the MAMP servers then the migrate worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

change .env file in laravel :
add MAMP mysql port

```
'mysql' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
        'port'      => '8889',
        'strict'    => false,
    ],
```

Jeff

Answer (score 0):

Yes, had exactly this problem, with MAMP need to add to config/database 'port' => '8889' (assuming yu are using this port, rather than 80 which can cause conflicts with others apps like Skype!)